# Dealing with an old, cast iron toilet flange

Tags: toilet

I decided to try and replace a leaky toilet in the house, so I bought a new toilet and ripped out the old one.

The flange is cast iron I think (our house was built in 1955 so I was kind of expecting that, but was really hoping that there would be a PCV one in there). The screws that secure the toilet to the flange were completely rusted. Here are some images of the flange, along with the drain pipe as viewed from the basement (please excuse the filth):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now, I'm not really sure what to do with this old flange. Can I just clean it up and use it for the new toilet? Or does it definitely need to be replace? Removing it looks like it might be a huge pain in the neck.

EDIT: After using some brass pads on the flange, it seems as if it may not be cast iron after all. There is no audible clang when I tap it with my wrench. Here is a photo:

[image]

Comment: If not broken don't try to fix it.  A bit of cleaning and it is good as new.

Comment: I would be more concern about some of the flooring(sub floor).  One piece seems iffy.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the flange.

Answer (score 4):

Clean it up and use stainless steel or brass (not plated, solid brass) hardware for mounting the toilet this time (stainless steel is probably less expensive.)

As noted in a comment there's some concerning damage to the subfloor. If not tackling that now, consider using some rotten wood stabilizer on it and getting a new support board under that area after doing that, to buy some more time.